# LWC - Updating date field

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Trying to update the following fields,Date field is not updating in `updateRecord`.( Other Fields got updated with correct value).

When i console.log the `new Date()` it print as below.

`Sat Apr 04 2020 19:14:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

```
import PAYMENT_DATE from "@salesforce/schema/SCInvoice__c.Payment_Date__c";
import INVOICE_ID from "@salesforce/schema/SCInvoice__c.Id";
import STAGE from "@salesforce/schema/SCInvoice__c.Stage__c";
import { updateRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

handlePayByCash() {
var d = new Date();

fields[INVOICE_ID.fieldApiName] = this.invoiceRecordId;
fields[PAYMENT_DATE.fieldApiName] = d;
fields[STAGE.fieldApiName] = "Payment Received";

 updateRecord(recordInput)
    .then(() => {
      this.variant = "success";
      this.title = "Success";
      this.message = "Payment Received!"; 
    })
    .catch(error => {

    });


}
```

Comment: I am assuming it is looking for `YYYY-MM-DD` format, not the Javascript date string. You can use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to format the date or toISOString if it is a date time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of cases The first case would be

**If the field is a Date/Time Field**

```
let date = new Date().toISOString();
```

**If the Field is just a Date Field**

```
 let dateTime = new Date(),
     date = ${dateTime.getFullYear()}-${dateTime.getMonth()}-${dateTime.getDate()};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with `new Date().toISOString()`, It's Working.

Print as `2020-04-04T14:52:23.970Z`